# How can I position a JButton under a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, layout-manager

How can I position a `JButton` under a `JTable`?  What kind of layouts? How? I have a `JTable` table what is scrollable, and the table is in a frame.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the [tutorials on the use of the layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) at the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)? If so, what about the tutorials *specifically* is confusing you?

Comment: I tried frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
it works but the button is fill the half frame!

Comment: there are more layouts than GridLayout. Please keep reading the tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many layouts to fulfill this need.

The simplest is using BorderLayout:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(jtable), BorderLayout.CENTER);
contentPane.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

If you want this button to be not resized just add `JPanel` to `contentPane`. This `JPanel` should contain your button centered using almost any layout.

If you would like to use more sophisticated layout - the best in my opinion is [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Comment: @TamásNyiri : Or you can add the `JButton` to the `JPanel` first and then add it to the `content pane` at the `PAGE_END` location later on, so that it's size remain normal even on resizing :-)

Answer (score 3):

To correct LoveToCode's well-meaning but misleading advice, you would never want to give a JTable itself a layout. The solution to your problem is not to set the JTable's layout but to set the layout for the JPanel that holds both the JTable's JScrollPane and the JButton. Likely a BorderLayout would work best with the JScrollPane being placed BorderLayout.CENTER and the JPanel that holds the JButton BorderLayout.SOUTH.

Note, if you're adding these components to the JFrame, then know that its contentPane already uses BorderLayout (the tutorials will tell you this -- please read them). So just add these guys to the contentPane as described above.

Answer (score 1):

If hard coding of swing and awt is not mandatory, try using the WindowsBuilder Pro, a Free tool now from google, install its plugin in to eclipse, then Use

GroupLayout - Introduced by NetBeans team in 2005 integrated in WindowsBuilder Pro, is one of the most convenient way create a good gui in less time in Java.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you can set the layout of a jtable the same way in which you can set the layout of a jframe or a jpane:
table.setLayout(new grideLayout(4, 3)
would give it a grid layout with 4 rows and 3 columns. 
the scrollable feature allows you to 'scroll' through your table with the moving bar. It may be a default feature, or it may be that you must use it, try seeing what methods your table gives you. 
Lastly, your table should be in a frame, so that you can view it on your window, make you class extend JFrame and it will automatically be a frame upon which you can simply add a table!

Comment: You would never want to give a JTable itself a layout. Ever.